# My monotouch application refuses to compile for distribution with Array index is out of range

Tags: compilation, xamarin.ios, distribution, enterprise

I am unable to compile my app in Monotouch when I select the full enterprise distribution profile I have setup. All the other profiles work ok.

To be specific: when I hit the build button I get

Detecting signing identity...

0 errors 0 warnings, just Build failed. Array index out of range

I am guessing this is a provisioning issue and I have failed to do something important.

There are pointers on the web to adhoc ditribution builds but no real documentation on full enterprise distribution.

I have the following:

Monotouch : Enterprise edition

Apple     : Enterprise membership, have installed the corp certificate & dev user certificate and downloaded the provisioning certificates for dev, adhoc & enterprise and finally created the App ID.

I have spent 2 days scouring the web for similar problems but have found nothing really close. At one point I scrubbed all my profiles with Apple Dev site and re imported them and this resolved some other issues I was having.

Having the full enterprise rights/certificate means I do not need UDIDs, I just have to sign my life away to prevent illegal ditribution. The only thing other than just plain missing something on the provisioning front is that the UDID's are held in an array in the certificates and as I have none specified for this build it errors out. (But it shouldn't surely!)

If I use the adhoc distribution which as UDID's specified in it I can load it on my machine.

Any pointers would be greatly received

Comment: Do you have a more complete error message? You should be able to find one in ~/Library/Logs/MonoDevelop/MonoDevelop.log

Comment: mhutch : thanks for the response. I managed to rectify the problem, so for the benefit of others who may have a similar issue this is where my problem was;

Comment: Continued.. hit the enter button (duh). It was a provisionig issue and after much delving arounf and careful reading of what was on my certificates and provisioning profiles I noticed that the corp enterprise bundle identifier did not need the appname tagged on the end of it. The moral of the story is you need to ensure that all the provisioning items are all correct and matched up. It was my first post on the forum and someone responded. Thanks

Comment: Tim, the practice is to answer not in a small comment, but as a full answer.

Comment: Miguel, I hear what you say.....next time I will conform.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation.

"mtouch failed to build".  No other messages.

Had to go through tech support and eventually found it was a compiler bug and they sent me a patch for my particular case.  I assume it will come out in the next release.

However, I did learn two things along the way that may help you.

a) in my case the problem went away if I changed the "Linker Behavior" setting for the project.  Project-> [project] Options -> Build -> iPhone Build -> Linker Behavior

Try all available options.  See if makes a difference.

b) On the same iPhone Build options page you can enter "-v -v -v" to the "extra arguments setting.  Now check the build output after compiling.  There may be additional details.

Finally, I pulled my hair out for a few days with an error similar to yours.  In the end it was a compiler bug.  Novell was quite quick to identify and fix the bug.  Maybe just log it with them and see what happens.

Good luck

Comment: Thrag, thanks for your input. I have had this error a number of times on different machines so next time I get it and it is not the result of my stupidity (not getting the provisioning names correct) I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when switching between my "test" and "release" builds, which had different app identifiers -- I'd switched to the "release" provisioning profile, but I forgot to fix the app display name and app identifier under Build / iPhone Application. Doubt the display name makes a difference but the app identifier certainly does.